# Python: Can't read last appended lines in file

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
#module1
from module2 import reader

def registration(userName, password, fileName, delimiter):
    with open(fileName, 'a') as file:
        file.write(userName + delimiter + password + '\n')
    return reader(fileName, delimiter)


#module2
def reader(fileName, delimiter):
    retVal = []
    with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            pair = line.split(delimiter)
            pair[1] = pair[1].strip()
            retVal.append(pair)
    return retVal
```

Now, what I should get is a list of lists that have the username and password strings. The reader does read the entries previously written, but doesn't read the one that was just added via the registration function. If I call the `reader` function twice (one more time before the return), my registration function does return the correct list (with the newly appended user).

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this here (using Python 3.4.1 on Win7 x64). What is your setup?

Comment: Try adding file.close() after you write.

Comment: The `with` statement already closes the file properly: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having an issue with the main method I used to call these functions. Since both modules had a separate main that prints out the result of the function (and that main is being called explicitly in the module file) the main from the reader was being activated when I imported the function (which is something I didn't know python did, especially not when I used the `from` keyword).

Anyway, sorry for the false alarm.